# Processing event hub data using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I am using azure event hub python SDK to send to and receive messages from event hub following this link.https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/tree/develop. I can successfully send and receive messages. But how do i parse the messages and retrieve the data from the event data object. Please find the code below.

```
import os
import sys
#import logging
from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset

ADDRESS = 'sb://####.servicebus.windows.net/#####'
USER = '##########'
KEY = '##################################'
CONSUMER_GROUP = "$default"
OFFSET = Offset("-1")
PARTITION = "1"


total = 0
last_sn = -1
last_offset = "-1"

try:
  if not ADDRESS:
      raise ValueError("No EventHubs URL supplied.")
  client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)
  receiver = client.add_receiver(CONSUMER_GROUP, PARTITION, prefetch=5000, 
  offset=OFFSET)
  client.run()
  try:
      batched_events = receiver.receive(timeout=20)
  except:
      raise
  finally:
      client.stop()
  for event_data in batched_events:
      last_offset = event_data.offset.value
      last_sn = event_data.sequence_number
      total += 1
      print("Partition {}, Received {}, sn={} offset={}".format(
         PARTITION,
         total,
         last_sn,
         last_offset))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
   pass
```

if i try to view the event_data received i can see the below message.
event_data 
`<azure.eventhub.common.EventData at 0xd4f1358>`
event_data.message

```
<uamqp.message.Message at 0xd4f1240>
```

Any help on the above on how to parse this message to extract the data

Comment: Try `event_data.body`

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/azure/eventhub/common.py#L185

Comment: It gives me this  <generator object data at 0x000000000D547DB0>. how to get the str data from this. Any suggestion?

Comment: It is a generator object, it will return a value on every next call i.e. `next(event_data.body)`. If you want all the values at once, do `list(event_data.body)`.

Comment: @Shiva You could add it as an answer, if it solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks @TomSun, posted an elaborate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of [`1.1.0`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/releases/tag/v1.1.0), there are new utility methods to extract the actual data of the message:

- [`body_as_str`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/azure/eventhub/common.py#L201)
- [`body_as_json`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/azure/eventhub/common.py#L222)

So, what used to be

```
import json
event_obj = json.loads(next(event_data.body).decode('UTF-8'))
```

Is now:

```
event_obj = event_data.body_as_json()
```

Answer (score 1):

For people using the Event Hub version 5.2.0 -- latest as of today ([GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub), [Reference Docs](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-eventhub/latest/azure.eventhub.html)), it's the same as the 1.1.0 version, i.e. use `body_as_str()` or `body_as_json()`. But the client has changed -- there's an `EventHubProducerClient` and an `EventHubConsumerClient` in the new version. To print the body of an event received:

```
from azure.eventhub import EventHubConsumerClient

connection_str = '<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>'
consumer_group = '<< CONSUMER GROUP >>'
eventhub_name = '<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>'

client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        connection_str, consumer_group, eventhub_name=eventhub_name
    )

def on_event_batch(partition_context, events):
    partition_context.update_checkpoint()
    for e in events:
        print(e.body_as_str())

with client:
    client.receive_batch(
        on_event_batch=on_event_batch,
        starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
    )
```